# please help to fix in magento Cannot initialize the indexer process.

Tags: magento

i tried all of tricks which i found on google for solving it but unable to fix it please help me about it also tr`DELETE cpop.* FROM catalog_product_option_price AS cpop
INNER JOIN catalog_product_option AS cpo
ON cpo.option_id = cpop.option_id
WHERE
cpo.type = ‘checkbox’ OR
cpo.type = ‘radio’ OR
cpo.type = ‘drop_down’;DELETE cpotp.* FROM catalog_product_option_type_price AS cpotp
INNER JOIN catalog_product_option_type_value AS cpotv
ON cpotv.option_type_id = cpotp.option_type_id
INNER JOIN catalog_product_option AS cpo
ON cpotv.option_id = cpo.option_id
WHERE
cpo.type <> ‘checkbox’ AND
cpo.type <> ‘radio’ AND
cpo.type <> ‘drop_down’;`

Answer (score 0):

Try to insert this in your SQL command console

```
ALTER TABLE catalog_category_entity ENGINE=INNODB; 
ALTER TABLE core_store ENGINE=INNODB;
```

I don't know what kind of issue do you have, but this is very helpful for many problems. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it via a custom module or script in phtml

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
   $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);
   $process->reindexAll();
}
```